# What is the difference between `(x: number) => void` and `function(number) : void` syntax for parameter types?

Tags: typescript, intellisense, jsdoc

When creating a javascript function that takes a callback as argument, I can add types for IntelliSense like so:

```js
/**
 * @param {function(number) : void} cb
 */
function takesCallback1(cb) {}
```

or like so

```js
/**
 * @param {(x: number) => void} cb
 */
function takesCallback2(cb) {}
```

What's the difference between the two and which should be used for what situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function() :` is JSDoc syntax whereas `() =>` is TypeScript syntax. Both are supported by IntelliSense, but the former is only supported inside JSDoc comments.

```
type TypeScriptSignature = (x: number) => void;
type JSDocSignature = function(number) : void;
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-JSDoc types can only be used inside
//                                            documentation comments. TS8020
```

Other than that the only significant difference between the two is that TypeScript syntax allows you to specify the name of the arguments.

If you hover over the two `cb` arguments of [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhCgAIUgBAHAhgJ0QW0gbwGYFcB2AxgC4CWA9vgBT65oBGApsgJSQBckAbuaQCYBfSIXpQQwcHiJlKkYogDWjAM4BhRABsN9RIQUBGKiLaYB4YMEhXrN23cgA9B+cv23dqigDmABk60GZjYAXgA+bl4+cHMwMTgkVAxMKgAPfzomVkgwiP4hETEJKRIKfDlFFXUtHT0AJiN6EzMLd1brJxc2ttT0wKycnn4gA), you'll see that the JSDoc type gets converted to the Typescript type with the argument name set to `arg0`.

```js
/**
 * @param {function(number) : void} cb
 */
function takesCallback1(cb) {}
//                      ^^
//                      (arg0: number) => void

/**
 * @param {(x: number) => void} cb
 */
function takesCallback2(cb) {}
//                      ^^
//                      (x: number) => void
```

---

So which one should you use? If you're generating docs using JSDoc.app, you should use the JSDoc type. If you're only concerned about IntelliSense getting things right, either will work, but the TypeScript syntax allows you to specify the argument name.